# How to get the first portion of object printed by console.log

Tags: javascript, object

I have an error object, I have printed it using the code:  `console.log(error);`

The console printed value is:

```
SigninError {id: "el-20003", description: ""}
```

[image]

I need to get the "SigninError" as string. How to get that?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: I guess it's `error.message` or something like that. It depends on how you throw that error.

Answer (score 2):

That string is probably the class name of the object. You can get it like so:

`console.log(error.constructor.name)`

Note:
This may or may not work for you depending on how the Error object class was instantiated and whether or not you use a destructive minifier or a code mangler.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys(error)` to get the keys of `error` object as an array and then use `toString()` to change it to string value:

```js
let error = {
 SigninError:{id: "el-20003", description: ""}
}
var keys = Object.keys(error);
console.log(keys.toString());
```

Comment: I need only "SigninError" as string.

Comment: @I.Ahmed Is that what you need as string for the value of `SigninError`?

Comment: Yes. But SigninError is have extended from Error object.

Comment: JSON.stringify(error.SigninError); gives undefined as SigninError is not property of error.